# Is there a Bitcoin wallet app for Android which allows me to quickly generate say 50 addresses, label them and...

Tags: wallet

Is there a Bitcoin wallet app for Android which allows me to quickly generate say 50 addresses, label them and then export the whole list to a text file or copy/paste all at once (not one by one)?

I think the title says it all.

I want a bitcoin wallet app with these features:

-Should be possible to quickly generate 50 addresses or more and label them
-The list of addresses should be exportable to text file or possible to copy/paste all addresses at once as opposed to copying address by address.

Anyone knows of such an app and has a link?

Vesa